# How do I tell the client they gave the wrong password?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, pug

I have a node.js web app, and I'm working on getting the user logged in and authenticated.  I'm using pug to template things, mysql, and express.js.

I use bcrypt for hashing the password, and that's all working right.  My problem lies with what to do when the password is incorrect, and how to tell that to the client, as the checking happens on the server.

Initially I was using socket.io, but I moved away from that.  Then, I used a redirect to `/login?error=true`.  Now that I'm using pug templating, it can't find the view.  One solution would be to simply redirect to a whole new page, `/loginfailure`, but I feel like I should be able to accomplish this without redirects.

I see `res.json()`, but when I use that, the client side renders it and I end up with a blank page that's just the json that I sent.  Is there a way to send json so I can do something with the json data client side, rather than have it just render the data?

What's the best way to send data from the server to the client, preferably not as a redirect?

I'm looking into AJAX now, and that seems like it has potential.  The issue I'm having is that if I use `res.send` or `res.json` it still renders the data, rather than passing it to the callback of the ajax call.  Suggestions?

Comment: Note: Do not indicate to the user wether it is the login ID or password that was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in express, and in whatever file you have your routes, you can implement an auth service to make sure that they are logged in to even see the rest of your api. Usually I'll give tokens to users, once they've been authenticated then I would let them see the rest. You can also use a service like ui-router and create states for your app, and if they don't have correct login credentials typically they would stay at the home page which would be the redirect. You could also alert them with a modal or something saying invalid email/password.